# deserialize json sting to genric list ( Error converting value to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 Path '', line 1, position 70

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, generics

here am facing little bit problem while deserializing json string to list

json string :  Result of restful service

"\"{\\"UName\\":\\"prasad\\",\\"LastName\\":\\"k\\",\\"FirstName\\":\\"sai\\"}\""

and i want to convert this json string to genric list

my list :

public class _TempUser
      {

```
      public string UName
      {
          get;
          set;

      }


      public string LastName
      {
          get;
          set;
      }

      public string FirstName
      {
          get;
          set;
      }
  }
```

Error is

Error converting value "{"UName":"prasad","LastName":"k","FirstName":"sai"}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[loginServices.Login_Service+_TempUser]'. Path '', line 1, position 70.

code : for calling restful service

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http ://IpAddress:Post/Login/RestServiceName.svc/RestMethoName");

```
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Req);
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                 string result =  streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                List<_TempUser> List = new List<_TempUser>();  

                List = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<_TempUser>>result     
            }

        }
```

any modifications or suggestions plz

Answer (score 0):

First your json string must be like this:

```
"{\"UName\":\"prasad\",\"LastName\":\"k\",\"FirstName\":\"sai\"}"
```

NOT

```
"\"{\\"UName\\":\\"prasad\\",\\"LastName\\":\\"k\\",\\"FirstName\\":\\"sai\\"}\""
```

Then you can parse it using:

```
string entry = "{\"UName\":\"prasad\",\"LastName\":\"k\",\"FirstName\":\"sai\"}";
var parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(entry);
        foreach (var dataset in parsedObject.Properties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataset.Name);
        }
```

I am using Newtonsoft.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.Linq for the parsing.

Comment: while using this  its getting error like this \                                     Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

Comment: string result =  streamReader.ReadToEnd();  here result="{\"UName\":\"prasad\",\"LastName\":\"k\",\"FirstName\":\"sai\"}"  and error is  Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using because I cannot reproduce that error on my side.

Comment: var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
        string result =  streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  var parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(result);
           foreach (var dataset in parsedObject.Properties())
                    {
                        string ss = dataset.Name;
                    }     
            }

Comment: Does it work if you declare your string (Do not get it from the service). This is what I'm doing...
string jsonObject1 = "{\"UName\":\"prasad\",\"LastName\":\"k\",\"FirstName\":\"sai\"}";


            var parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonObject1);
            foreach (var dataset in parsedObject.Properties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dataset.Name);
            }